# How is the LSP implemented in web editors?

Tags: language-server-protocol, gitpod

I've been studying the Language Server Protocol recently. Correct me if I'm wrong - from what I understand, the language server seems to be an actual server running on the user's machine in a separate process from the code editor (or IDE), that communicates with the IDE through websockets.

If that's true, how do web-based code editors (like Gitpod and GitHub Codespaces) work? Do they use self-hosted language servers for the major languages? Or do they just do away with the websocket transport layer and use a modified version of language servers like an in-memory object?

Comment: There are several possible options, 1) LSP supports remote connections, not just local.
2) VSCode Remote development. Gitpod and GitHub Codespaces all have virtual machines in the background, so not surprised that they can work.

Comment: 1) I know, but you'll still need a separately hosted language server for online editors, no? A website can't communicate with a locally running server. 2) Yeah, I think this is the most likely option of how it works.